# Kendo grid/datasource/grouping

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

Ok I have a grid setup binding to local data

Here it is based on the examples in the kendo demos
http://dojo.telerik.com/@marcushaslam/ovOKo

I'm having problems when rows are deleted. They appear to be deleted but then the original rows re-appear when columns are grouped.

Grouping works when 1 row is left - delete both rows (they disappear) group by a column and the original 2 come back!

I thought that the datasource automatically updated based on the destroy events. Am I missing something that will update the original data array from the datasource?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing transport configuration, that will update correctly the array and the grid. Please check this article that explains how to implement transport functionality with local data:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/how-to/grid-localstorage-crud